# How to display an UITableViewCell using xib on iOS 13.3?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, xib

How to display a cell using xib?
On devices prior to iOS 13 this method shows a cell, since iOS 13 it doesn't.
`SurveyFacultyCell` is name of a `.xib` custom table view cell

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:SurveyFacultyCell? = tblView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "surveyFacultyCell") as? SurveyFacultyCell

    if cell == nil {
        tblView.register(UINib(nibName: "SurveyFacultyCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "surveyFacultyCell")
        cell = tblView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "surveyFacultyCell") as? SurveyFacultyCell
    }
    cell?.selectionStyle = .none
    cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    let dictFaculty = arrFaculty[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary

    print(dictFaculty)

    cell?.lblName.text = dictFaculty.string(forKey: "facultyName")
    print(cell?.lblName.text as Any)
}
```

Comment: Move the `tblView.register...` to `viewDidLoad`, you don't need it in cellForRow

Comment: @Tj3n This whole tblView.register(UINib(nibName: "SurveyFacultyCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "surveyFacultyCell")

Comment: also I would recommend to set `selectionStyle` and `contentView.backgroundColor` from Storyboard or in `SurveyFacultyCell` (at `awakeFromNib()`) . It's not good idea to set it at `cellForRowAt`

Comment: And while creating the cell's instance, use `as! SurveyFacultyCell` instead of `as? SurveyFacultyCell` because if the cell type does not exist(which should never happen because it should be right there), your program should crash

Comment: Its look like you forgot to return your cell. Add return cell at the end of your statement

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. The question needs more focus. What is the actual result? What is displayed? The problem could be inside the cell class.

Answer (score 0):

You are registering Xib in a wrong way. Simple register it at `viewDidLoad()`. 
I am telling you how to `Xib registering` not your `logic`.

Here's my answer:

**Register xib on viewDidLoad()**

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "SurveyFacultyCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SurveyFacultyCell")
```

**cellForRowAt:**

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "surveyFacultyCell", for: indexPath) as! SurveyFacultyCell

 ... Your logic ... 

return cell
```

**Complete**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "SurveyFacultyCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SurveyFacultyCell")
    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "surveyFacultyCell", for: indexPath) as! SurveyFacultyCell

        cell?.selectionStyle = .none
        cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        let dictFaculty = arrFaculty[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary

        print(dictFaculty)

        cell?.lblName.text = dictFaculty.string(forKey: "facultyName")
        print(cell?.lblName.text as Any)
}
```

Comment: Registering in `cellForRow` is not wrong and it will work without problems. You have improved code style but you haven't fixed anything.

Comment: @Muju I am using same coding practice, No issues in iphone8 or iphone11

Answer (score -1):

Put this in your viewDidLoad

```
tblView.register(UINib(nibName: "SurveyFacultyCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "surveyFacultyCell")
```

If you are registering a cell like this, the `dequeReusableCell` method will create a cell for you if there is no cell to reuse.
Hence you don't need to check for a nil cell in you `cellForRow` method

Comment: in iPhone 6s it is working fine but in iPhone 8 it is not working